# Array of image canvas HTML5

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I'm trying to make a card game in HTML5 with Canvas, but I have a problem when I try to draw 3 card at center of my canvas.

Error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'drawImage' on 'CanvasRenderingContext2D': The provided value is not of type '(HTMLImageElement or HTMLVideoElement or HTMLCanvasElement or ImageBitmap)'

My Code:

```
if (tableCard.length > 0)
{
    var x = 0;
    var y = 180;
    var tableImage = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < tableCard.length; i++)
    {                                                
        tableImage[i] = new Image();

        tableImage[i].onload = function () {                            
            context.drawImage(tableImage[i], x, y);
        };
        x = +90;
        carterimanenti = deckOfCard.length;
        tableImage[i].src = tableCard[i].picture;
    }
}
```

where tableCard

```
for(var i=0; i<3; i++)
{
    var cartaU = drawRandomCard();
    tableCard.push(new Card(cartaU.Name, cartaU.semeTipo, cartaU.CardValue, cartaU.picture));
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript closure inside loops – simple practical example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to refer to an indexing variable in a callback. When the callback is executed this variable's value is out of bounds of your array:

```
context.drawImage(tableImage[**i**], x, y);
```

You will need to extract the applicable image element in another way:

```
tableImage[i].onload = function (event) {
    context.drawImage(event.target, x, y);
};
```

Now I notice that your `x` and `y` coordinates are also referenced in the closure. This will also not work. You will need to store the x and y as attributes or data of the image element. You can do something like this:

```
var image = tableImage[i];
image.setAttribute("data-x", x);
image.setAttribute("data-y", y);
tableImage[i].onload = function () {
    var image = event.target,
        x = parseInt(image.getAttribute("data-x", 10),
        y = parseInt(image.getAttribute("data-y", 10);                          
    context.drawImage(image, x, y);
};
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks  alot you fixed my error, but how and where i need to store the X and Y attributes? 
Sorry i'm a student !